# Phonegap video streaming Chat application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a project where I need to do a PC to mobile chat application in android and iOS, I was thinking if that could be possible using phonegap?

I searched a little and found this plugin for capturing video

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin

Will it work?

Ok, to add more the backend will be in .net azure server and front end will be the mobile/tablet device and a user should be able to communicate with the admin/supervisor PC web browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a livechat, then the plugin will be of no use. I created it for recording video and when recording is done, the result can be played back or sent to a server. Live streaming is not supported.

Best regards,
Eddy